# Invalid workflow syntax

Tags: workflow, youtrack

I have a workflow that closes an issue whenever the text "#close" is present on comment. Any idea why [text.contains()](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.1/Workflow-String-Date-Operations.html#contains) is displayed as an error.

```
when comments.added.isNotEmpty { 
  if (!issue.isResolved()) { 
    var myComment = comments.added.first; 

    var commentText = myComment.text; 

    if (myComment.text.contains("#close", true) { 
      issue.State = {Fixed}; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: The reason I showed the screenshot is because it shows the error; had I not included the screenshot users would have doubted my claim given that the documentation shows otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to my problem. Not sure if its intended or a bug.

The error on my original post occurs when the method name is typed; the workaround is to use autocomplete(Ctrl+space) and select the desired function.

Comment: It's intended. Workflow editor is not a text editor and requires a lot of Ctrl + Space hits to complete things.